# Coexistance of Hadoop MR1 and MR2

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

Is is possible to run both Hadoop MR1 and MR2 together in same cluster (at least, in theory)?

If yes, how can I do that?

Answer (score 4):

In theory, you can do as:

- run DataNode TaskTracker and NodeManager on one machine
- run NameNode SecondaryNameNode and ResourceManager on other machines
- all processes with different ports

but, not suggest to do this, see [cloudera blog](https://ccp.cloudera.com/display/CDH4DOC/Deploying+MapReduce+v2+%28YARN%29+on+a+Cluster#DeployingMapReducev2%28YARN%29onaCluster-Step9):

> "Make sure you are not trying to run MRv1 and YARN on the same set of nodes at the same time. This is not supported; it will degrade performance and may result in an unstable cluster deployment."

Answer (score 0):

In theory, yes.

1. Unpack the tarball into 2 different locations, owned by different users.
2. In both of them, change all mapred/yarn related ports to mutually exclusive sets.
3. Run the datanodes from only one of the locations.
4. Start mapred/yarn related daemons in both locations

Do post here if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Also dfs name dir and data dir should be different for MR1 and MR2.

```
<property>
    <name>dfs.name.dir</name>
    <value>/home/userx/hdfs/name</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>dfs.data.dir</name>
    <value>/home/userx/hdfs/data</value>
</property>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems for Mapr, this is not only a theory but practice, check this [link](https://www.mapr.com/blog/memory-management-calculations-clusters-running-both-mr1-and-mr2-services).

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to run both, just run the Hadoop 2.0, it provides full backward compatibility to MapReduce applications written for Hadoop 1.0. 
There are few minor changes in API, please look at the [link](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduce_Compatibility_Hadoop1_Hadoop2.html) to check if any changes effect your applications.